# Kivy: How to make a checkbox "remember" its state/value?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make a login screen with a "remember login" feature, a checkbox that, when toggled, will store all user credentials in a text file to access later. I want the app to remember the value of the checkmark so that when I open it again, the checkmark is in the "on" or "off" position, depending on its previous input. I was thinking of using a text file with a boolean condition stored inside. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the value to a ini file and read it on launch